# Inject a preprocessor definition into the Eclipse parser for a certain file type?

Tags: cuda, c-preprocessor, eclipse-cdt, nsight

I'm using Eclipse CDT (actually, nVIDIA's nSight, but the same goes for both) to edit some source files. Now, some of these are meant for use both with nvcc and with regular host-side compilers, and have some instances of:

```
#ifdef __CUDACC__
something
#else
some other thing
#endif
```

I want to get the `__CUDACC__` part when the preprocessor is reaching a file while parsing a `.cuh` or `.cu`, but not when reaching it while parsing a `.h` or `.cpp` (or `.c`). Now, I know I can inject a preprocessor define through the project settings (using the "built-in compiler" command line), but I was wondering whether it's possible to make that conditional on the extension of the file being parsed originally (i.e. the file being edited in the IDE).

Answer (score 1):

How are you configuring the project's include paths and defined macros?

If you use the Build Output Parser, can you arrange for the build system to include `-D __CUDACC__` in the compiler commands for `.cu` files, but not for the compiler commands for `.cpp` files?

CDT allows for each file in the project to have its own settings, and the Build Output Parser will assign each file that has a compilation command in the build output its own settings based on the flags that appear in the command, so things should just work.

Comment: So, you're suggesting I set this for individual (all) the individual `.cu` files?

Comment: "How are you configuring the project's include paths" <- Umm, just set some include paths in (Project) Properties | C/C++ General | Paths and Symbols | Includes | GNU C++

Comment: Well, I'm not suggesting you do it manually for all `.cu` files, but if you use something like the Build Output Parser, it's done automatically for you. The only thing you'd have to do is make sure the build output includes `-D __CUDACC__` for each `.cu` file, which might already be the case, but even if not should be a matter of a simple modification to your makefile / CMakeLists.txt / etc.